# Unable to connect Android emulator to React Native debugger

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

I am unable to connect android emulator with react native debugger.

When I run `react-native run-android`, it brings up the app successfully without showing any errors. It also brings up node Metro Bundler as well. But it didn't print any logs in RN debugger. When I press Reload app on the page, it shows the following popup error:

> React Native: No apps connected
>   Sending 'reload' to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone

[Popup error when press on RN debugger "Reload app" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB0gh.png)

I tried running this `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` but it doesn't work. When I press Cmd+m in my emulator, it is showing multi-touch. So I can't open developer menu as well.

[unintentional triggered when pressed Cmd+m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY8Dp.png)

```
System:
    OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
    Memory: 60.96 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
    Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: ^0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you enable debug mode on emulator?

Comment: I am unable to open debugger as page is not loading properly.

Comment: I add the same problem but in my case, just reactivate the internet connection on the emulator works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that page was not loading properly after my RN version update from 0.59 to 0.6. I believe it has some other issues as well since I haven't tested in android from the very beginning. So, I just created a fresh project and imported all the files manually. Might not be the answer which you are looking for but that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator means real device or Android studio?

if you are trying to connect emulator from android studio please uninstall the device and install the Pixel 2 it may help you.

And Uninstall the React native debugger and install the latest one